# Rails form submit for two different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, sunspot

I'm working on a simple webapp in which you import a CSV and search through it using Sunspot.  The only actions being used by the user are Index and Show.  All of this is working fine, but the end goal is to be able to track exactly what is being searched and export it.

My `datasheets` model is the one for the CSV being uploaded.  Again this including the search is working fine.  Both `datasheets` and `datalog` are scaffolded and routed by default.The first attempt at this I figured I would just add a definition in my `DatasheetsController` that will create a new instance of the `datalog` model using the search.

**datasheets_controller.rb** (working fine)

```
def index
  @search = Datasheet.search do
    fulltext params[:search]
  end

  @datasheets = @search.results
  
  respond_to do |format|
    ...
  end
end
```

Here's my attempt at creating a new datalog.  I'm new at Rails and realize this isn't RESTful, but I'm ok with a quick and dirty solution here.

```
class DatasheetsController < ApplicationController

  after_filter :log_it

  def log_it
    @datalog = Datalog.new(params[:datalog])
  end

end
```

This didn't do anything with nothing helpful in development.log, so I tried changing the params to `@datalog = Datalog.new(params[:search])` but it gave me a the following error:

```
NoMethodError in DatasheetsController#index

undefined method `stringify_keys` for "[whatever is searched for]":string
```

I'm sure I'm way off here but I figured this would be an easy thing to throw in, but it's not turning out to be.  If it helps, once this works I'd like to make the `datalog` attribute `:name` created to be the same as the string that was searched for.  Any point in the right direction (or smack for doing it so poorly) would be very much appreciated.

EDIT:  I'd also like to add that if there is a simple way to log search results (it doesn't have to be in a model), anything is welcome (including gems).  I've searched as many keyword variations as I could think of on Google and SO and haven't been able to find anything.

**EDIT 2:**

After editing a few things I've gotten closer, but I'm still having issues.

I've added the following to `def index`:

`@logkey = :search`

and changed the `log_it` definition to:

```
def log_it
  @datalog = Datalog.new(params[:id])
  @datalog.update_attribute(:name, @logkey)
end
```

Now a new Datalog will save on search which is great, but the `:name` attribute always ends up being "search".

An example table that I have right now for datalogs is:

---

### Name

search    Show Edit Destroy

search    Show Edit Destroy

search    Show Edit Destroy

search    Show Edit Destroy

search    Show Edit Destroy

New Datalog

---

I've tried changing the `@logkey` line to: `@logkey = :search.to_s` but it doesn't really effect anything.

**EDIT in response to answer**

SQL (0.5ms) INSERT INTO "datalogs" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 26 Feb 2013 18:26:04 UTC +00:00], ["name", nil], ["updated_at", Tue, 26 Feb 2013 18:26:04 UTC +00:00]]

Again if this is just a problem elsewhere I get that and I can look for it on my own time.  Thanks again!

Comment: `@logkey = params[:search].to_s` however see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the following:

- I am assuming that your Datalog model is derived from `ActiveRecord::Base` (standard way of doing models in rails)
- `.new` method of this class ([documented here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new/class)) takes an attribute hash (and options, but we don't care about that right now )

  - from this hash `.new` tries to create an instance of the class using every key-value pair of the hash in a way that the instances key-named attribute should be set as the value
- the problem is that `params[:search]` in your example can not be used as an argument for `.new`, so it throws an exception

How it should look like:

- in the Datalog model you should have something like: `:attr_accessor name`
- params should `params[:search] = { :name => 'My favourite search name' }`

**Another notes**
If you're running simply `bundle exec rails s` you can see your params in the server log. In production just use: `less log/development.log`. You can check what are you sending trough for your application.

**Update after question update**

`@logkey = params[:search].to_s`

**Update after comment**

Ok this `@datalog.update_attribute(:name, @logkey)` line is not necessary. Just go w/ your original one: `@datalog = Datalog.new(params[:datalog])` it is the "rails way".

Keep in mind my first part of the answer, so `params[:datalog]` should be a hash. However if you can't manage to do that then just use:

```
@datalog = Datalog.new(params[:id])
@datalog.name = params[:search] # I dont think to_s is needed
@datalog.save # To save it into the database
```

Comment: +1 Thank you so much for the great explanation, it makes a lot more sense now.  Unfortunately after implementing `:name` is nil.  I'm not getting any errors thrown in console or development.log.  I'm definitely aware that it's not your advice but most likely a problem that was already there.  I'll edit the SQL INSERT INTO line into my question if that helps.

Comment: Wow that last edit made it click for me.  I was making this way more difficult than it needed to be.  Thanks so much for all your help!